# NetBeanse 8.0.2 When increase font size; it is only applied on parts of the code!!! How to fix?

Tags: netbeans, fonts

[image: Code screen shot]

It is the first time I use this new **version** of NetBeanse 8.0.2 - I didn't encounter this problem in previous versions.

The default font size is normal, and is applied properly. But when I try to increase the font size, it is oddly applied to some parts!!!

To increase font size, I use this steps:
Tools > Options > Syntax > Language: Java
Then I change font size value.

How to fix this issue so that new font size is applied properly to all of the code?

Comment: Restart  netbeans first of all. Second of all by any chance did u change default font for methods from "Inherit" to another ?

Answer (score 0):

Illustration of it is underneath

[image]

Comment: No result; the same problem still exist.

Comment: It looks like it is a case. U screenshot as well has capitals exactly on method use. Anyway there is a was to reset settings of netbeans just move $USER_HOME/.netbeans director to .netbeans.old. U will need to import projects again manually, but all settings will be default.